# How to check when SwiftUI subscribed to published property of ObservableObject?

Tags: swiftui, observable, combine

I did this but the print statement is never called. What I am missing?

```
final class TestObservableObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    private (set) var publishedProperty: Int = 0
    var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>? = Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
    init() {
        self.objectWillChange = $publishedProperty.handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { (_) in
            print("receiveSubscription")
        }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    private var test: TestObservableObject
    init() {
        test = TestObservableObject()
    }
    var body: some View {
        return Group {
            if test.publishedProperty == 0 {
                Text("0")
            } else {
                Text("100")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah just changing

```
var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>?
```

to

```
var objectWillChange: AnyPublisher<Int, Never>
```

worked.